# Set button Layout in Android 2.2

Tags: android, layout, button, timer, position

I have a little problem here:
I want to make a button in my timer ... But I want to put in my view with random position ..
NOTE: I work at Android 2.2 API 8 .. 
thanks guys!

Here is my code:

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    final int i=1;
    Button a = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        new CountDownTimer(20000,1000) {

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //how to create a button here!
                LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainan);
                Button btn = new Button(NyaActivity.this);
                btn.setId(i+1);                    
                btn.setText("Button"+(i+1));    
                // i want to set position of button randomly ..                
                linearLayout.addView(btn);                                  
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        }.start();
    }
});
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Math.random()*width
```

where `width` is the maxValue of the range will give you a random x position, and you can do the same for the height of course

then you set your LinearLayout.LayoutParams

```
LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.setMargins(marginLeft, marginTop, 0, 0);
btn.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Voila, random position inside your layout

Comment: theres no setMargin methode in layoutparams .. :(

Comment: Make sure you import LinearLayout.LayoutParams

Comment: @AlvinChristian - Be specific in declaring the `LayoutParams`. For eg. `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params;`